# Получение постов с информацией об авторе через RxJava и Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava

Мне необходимо получать автора и посты для отображения в `RecyclerView` с `Header`. В `Header`, собственно, у меня будет находиться разметка с данными об авторе, а снизу будут посты. Думаю, как мне это реализовать. Накидал пару вариантов:

Первый вариант: Делать первый запрос через `Retrofit` и получать `Observable` с автором, в `onNext()` запускать следующий запрос, в нем уже получать посты от этого автора, объединять все это в один `Observable` и выдавать адаптеру. Довольно муторно и долго.

Второй вариант: Делать одновременно 2 запроса и как-то пытаться их синхронизировать, потом объединить их в один `Observable` и отдать адаптеру. Тут вопрос- как можно синхронизировать работу `Observable` от `Retrofit`? Предпочтительный вариант.

Третий вариант: Реализовать это на бэкэнде. В запросе передавать `id` автора. Возвращаться будет список постов с информацией об авторе на первом месте в этом массиве. Но тогда возникает вопрос с десериализацией. Если у меня объекты имплементируют общий интерфейс, как `GSON` поймет экземпляр какого класса я хочу получить после десериализации? Потому что в адаптер мне нужно передавать экземпляры 2 `POJO` классов (`User` и `Post`), соот-но они должны наследоваться от одного интерфейса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант можно упростить с помощью `flatMap` метода и `Pair` класса. Например так:

```
//получаем автора, потом получаем список его постов и отдаём `Pair`, в коем и то и другое
retrofitInterface.getAuthor(authorId)
    .flatMap(author->retrofitInterface.getAuthorPosts(authorId).flatMap(posts -> Observable.just(new Pair<Author, List<Post>>(author, posts))))
    .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidShedullers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(authorAndPosts->System.out.println(authorAndPosts.first, authorAndPosts.second));
```

Второй вариант - пускать параллельные запросы. Тут можно по разному - через `zip` или `combineLatest`. Первый - собирает результаты из каждого запроса и выпускает их вместе когда все запросы выпустят по элементу. Второй - точно также, но выпускает результаты при появлении следующего элемента в любом источнике. В вашем случае без разницы какой оператор использовать, но, концептуально, кмк, лучше `zip`. Как-то так:

```
Observable.zip(retrofitInterface.getAuthor(authorId), retrofitInterface.getAuthorPosts(authorId), (author, posts) -> new Pair<>(author, posts))
    .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidShedullers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(authorAndPosts->System.out.println(authorAndPosts.first, authorAndPosts.second));
```

Третий вариант, думаю, излишний. Незачем смешивать сущности.